# How can I determine which RAM module is failing Memtest86?

Tags: memory, hardware-failure, memtest86+

One or many of the memory cards out of total 4GB (4x1GB) are failing. 
The following is memtest progress screenshot. It is always pointing to memory at 19xx MB and 50xx MB. Error bits are always 04000000. How can I determine which of those 4 cards are failing? The strange thing is that if I test them individually they are not failing. I've change Motherboard.

[image: memtest]
[image: memtest]

Thanks

Comment: Maybe the modules are mis matched? Post your Motherboard model and revision.

Comment: If the modules do not fail individually, then that is not your problem.  I had this problem before, where I would get errors but they would be fine individually... Turns out it *was* the motherboard.  It is possible that you have tested the memory in two damaged motherboards.  Try bringing the RAM to a friend and testing it again.  (Oh, and BTW, +1 for posting pictures, much appreciated)

Comment: Also, I've noticed that the error bit is the same for each count.  Was this the case with both motherboards you tested?

Comment: @Moab: They were working for a long time and identical. MSI P45 Diamond.

Comment: @Breakthrough: Like I mentioned I've exchanged mobo once and now I have exactly same issue, same error bitmask. None of friends have DDR3 compatible mobos, unfortunately.

Comment: My next suggestion would be to test them in pairs and see if you can locate a specific pair that fails.

Comment: @Breakthrough: I still think it should be possible to locate exactly which modules are failing based on addresses.

Comment: @Breakthrough: both mobos are giving exactly same error bitmasks? less likely..

Comment: How long did you stress test the individual modules using memtest86?...there is a newer version 4.20...http://www.memtest.org/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the process of elimination -- remove half of the modules and run the test again...

If there are no failures, then you know that these two modules are good, so put them aside and test again.

If there are failures, then cut down to half again (down to one of four memory modules now) then test again.

But, just because one failed a test, don't assume that the other doesn't fail (you could have two failing memory modules) -- where you've detected a failure with two memory modules, test each of those two separately afterwards.

Important note:  With features like memory interleaving, and poor memory module socket numbering schemes by some motherboard vendors, it can be difficult to know which module is represented by a given address.

Comment: testing them individually does not show failure. I've tested like couple hours each.

Comment: +1. Try testing the modules in **pairs**, and if you're absolutely sure it's not the motherboard, use process of elimination to find the bad one.

Comment: anyway... located a pair of modules which is failing. However, individually each module is not failing, only with pair and rarely. they are identical and not overclocked.

Comment: Are those memory modules hot to the touch after failing a test?  If so, then it could be an overheating problem (and the modules may be fine in a system that doesn't cause them to run hot).

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old post but maybe someone will have the same problem. It could be that the problem appears when the mainboard is entering in dual channel configuration, so the problem could be from the processor, especially some of the the pins from underneath it could be bended.