# Memtest errors only when in dual channel

Tags: memtest

i have 32GB DD4 set (2x16GB stick ADATA XPG 32GB KIT DDR4 3000MHz CL16 GAMMIX D10). Experiencing occasional and very random BSOD (i play games, watch movies and fly flight sim - most of BSOD are during using flight sim for its high RAM demand, but occasionaly in games too). Can't even use "high" or "ultra" performance in Windows, that's for sure recipe for BSOD when gaming/flying. Also same for automatic OC profiles in BIOS, as soon as i enable it, PC refuses to boot and tells me that settings were found unstable and BIOS values returned to previous settings.

When testing with Memtest (from bootable USB), everything is fine, when testing single stick, no error during almost 4 hours test per stick (test is default config - 4 passes, all tests). Both sticks seem to be fine, tested in one same slot (the one of two i am using for dual-channel). I am using default BIOS setting for everything.

When testing both sticks in dual-channel, there are hundreds of errors from beginning.

I was thinking one of slot i am using could be faulty so i tested one of !already proven to be good" stick in second slot i am using in dual-channel. No errors either.

Could it be CPU? 9700k, but non-OC'ed. I also used IntelBurnTest for stability check and it yields errors on higher memory settings. I've already replaced mobo and power supply (EVGA SuperNova 750 G3), i know, i went not that good direction, i simply "thought" ;) it could be PSU or mobo first :/

Or could it be the RAM itself? Both sticks don't play well together (yet from one set)?

Mobo is MSI MAG Z390 Tomahawk, using slots B2+A2 (as stated in manual).

When testing single stick i used most accesable B2 (due CPU heatsink), now i see in mobo user manual single stick config is slot A1, not sure, if it could impacted results (no errors) with Memtest when testing single stick.

TYA and have a great day.

Comment: Both RAM slots are clean, devoid of dust, lint, etc...? Dual-channel performs operations in parallel, not serially, so it could mean that either one of your RAM stick is iffy, or the bus is overloaded for some reason (heat, probably, but could be something else too). Have you tried to enable Legacy Mode in your UEFI/BIOS, then run tests again?

Comment: Which slots are you using for dual channel and which motherboard do you have? PS. (please edit in your question instead of answering in the comments)

Comment: @Didier Thank you for reply :) I was using slots A2 + B2, all single stick tests were performed in B2 (no erros, yet i found that it is inproper slot for single stick config), then i tested one of stick in A2 just out of curiosity if slot could be bad or so - no errors either. Currently i am testing Memtest v4, which is last version supporting legacy boot, if am i correct? After 1st pass, all 10 tests, multiCPU, both sticks in A2+B2 - no errors so far (will let it go for another few hours (one pass was about 1 hr 45 mins, maybe will let it go over night). Does it say anything?

Comment: @BramMooij Thank you for reply :). Added info about mobo and used memory slots into my intial post/question.

Comment: Legacy Mode is often the most reliable way to test your RAM, especially in dual-channel, because it gives access to an extra-menu to choose from, between Fast, Standard and Extended options when it comes to test your RAM. In UEFI, you'll often (not always) be stuck with the Standard option. If your MemTest shows no errors in Legacy Mode, then it means your RAM is operational. Maybe not tip-top shape, but it works. With that much RAM, you shouldn't have any problem running RAM-hungry programs.

Comment: @Didier Memtest in legacy mode yielded one error (with 236 confidence) - range 890-910 MB after 5 hrs or so of testing. I let it run for another 15 hrs - 8 errors (on test 6, numbered from zero), range was like 2-26GB. Don't know, what to think, before such large range i was almost decided to go for new memory, but after that huge range ... How large is probability that both stick are in such bad condition? This makes me think it rather could be an memory controller in my 9600K? What's your opinion? Thanks in advance, i think this could be my last question.

Comment: You'll find a very comprehensive answer to your question here (https://superuser.com/questions/326078/how-do-i-interpret-the-statistics-of-a-memtest-run), as to how memtest runs, what it does, and how to interpret its results. It's possible that your upgrade put an unexpected strain on your memory controller, in terms of heat dissipation, and that it be bent, or has some defective contacts. It's also possible that under strain, as with memtest, one or both RAM sticks heat up and underperform. The bigger the sticks, the longer the test, the bigger the strain.

Comment: Thanks for updating. Just because it's a simple test I would also try running slot A1 and B1. Typically this would also work, despite the manual suggesting A2, B2. It would be interesting to see if this gives any different results. Testing A2 only could also be interesting, but that wouldn't solve your problem ;)

Comment: Sorry for late response, but i didn't want to put a premature info here. Decided to buy a new 32GB kit as it was "buy a new RAM" or "buy a new CPU", so price was a decision factor here (CPU costs more than double price of RAM in this case). So far so good, occasional CTDs and BSODs are gone, i can even enable XMP in BIOS without BIOS telling me that it is unstable setting, also Intel Burn Test at max settings (almost 30G of RAM) for like three hours, no CTD, no BSOD and perfect results.Memtest is also fine after more than 4.5 hrs of testing. Thanks for all help! @BramMooij

Comment: @Didier see mz previous comment, thanks are for you also! Unfortunately only one user can be noticed per one post, so i wrote this post to also notify you.

Comment: You're welcome! What matters is that your problem is solved, doesn't matter who provided "the right answer". Enjoy your new sticks!