# Interpreting memtest - 0 passes

Tags: memory, bsod, memtest

Since I encountered many bluescreen in the last time, I finally got to run the memtest86. I've already read [this](https://superuser.com/questions/326078/how-do-i-interpret-the-statistics-of-a-memtest-run) topic on how to interpret a memtest result, unfortunately it hasnt brought me any further in understanding what my memtest was showing me, as already the 'result mask' is looking quite different. 
Here's what I got:
[image: Image on imageshack] (Sorry for external link, I can't post images because of missing reputation)

My thought was that probably a whole 2GB Mem is not working, looking at the 'Highest Error Address' Part. What can I do with the Error Address it is giving me? Can I detect which Ram Part is 'bad' through this address? Also the fact that memtest has found 0(!) passes, but 10260 errors makes me wondering what this numbers really mean.

Any help would be highly appreciated, this bluescreens are getting really annoying.

Comment: The question you linked uses Memtest86+, which is a little different from the Memtest86 you are using. I personally use Memtest86+. In any case, you have many memory errors - this could be a faulty RAM stick, a faulty motherboard, or even a faulty CPU. There are several ways to isolate it, but you cannot rely on any specific bits reported in the test program since some locations may be shifted around from where they physically are, and some sticks might conflict. The question you linked has an answer that links [here](http://superuser.com/a/253938/117590), which might help.

Comment: Basically, you'll want to test your RAM in a known good motherboard, and/or test know good RAM in your motherboard, if possible. Also, try testing one stick at a time. Try testing in different slots. Try testing different combinations. Note that Memtest can take many iterations/passes (repeats of the same tests, where a test is a specific pattern) to find errors, so this may take a lot of time.

Comment: There was a period where memtest86 wasn't maintained. Memtestx86+ was a fork from that time IIRC